# When will I be able to use the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

When is the Chrome web store going to be able to be used?

The more specific the date range, the better - including predictions based on your knowledge.

Comment: This question is of little use now that the Chrome Web store has been open for several years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link for support for even more webapps. http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/07/06/more-google-chrome-web-apps/

It's actually rather easy to build your own, once you get the hang of it.

I currently use [facebook](http://facebook.com), [twitter](http://twitter.com), [grooveshark](http://listen.grooveshark.com), [meebo](http://meebo.com) and google mail for my domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can start using it right now for a few specific web apps with Google Chrome. Here's the tutorial:

[Lifehacker: Try Out Three Early Web Apps from the Chrome Web Store Now](http://lifehacker.com/5587455/try-out-three-early-web-apps-from-the-chrome-web-store-now)

Comment: Have seen that, it's pretty cool!

Comment: Here's a tip: If you edit the JSON file in notepad, then you can actually create a web app for every website you need.

Comment: Please **do not** use URL shorteners here.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, at the site: https://chrome.google.com/webstore

> The Chrome Web Store opens later this year. Users will be able to discover a broad range of amazing web apps while developers will be able to reach millions of new users.